# Android Unable to add window token null is not for an application within service

Tags: android, service, android-dialog

I am having a service from where I want to show a dialog.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
    private View formView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        formView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_widget, null);
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setView(formView);
        // some more code
    }

    public void onClick() {
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Now I know this issue is already solved by replacing `this` with `MyActivity.this`, but as this is service, I am not able to access it. It gives me this error: `com....MainActivity is not an enclosing class`

Also I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` in manifest file.

Comment: add this permission in manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

Comment: add dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

Comment: Cannot resolve method getWindow for dialog

Comment: use  dialog.create().getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

Comment: Same error I am getting: `Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`